# Verify if point is inside an elliptical cone

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry

I am trying to find a way to figure out whether a 3D point `P(x,y,z)` is in side a cone with an elliptical base or not.

I have given the vertex `V(x,y,z)`, the center of the base `B(x,y,z)`, and the length of the minor and major axis of an ellipse `a` and `b`, forming the base of a cone.

Is there any way to get an analytic equation descriping the cone? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768142/verify-if-point-is-inside-a-cone-in-3d-space) answer, which handles the problem for a circular cone, however I cannot extend it to work for my problem :(

Comment: I'm not seeing any c++ here.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You'll get a badge (c:

Comment: What is known about the orientation of elliptic base?

Comment: I know the plane where the base is lying in, and some points on the plane. I used a PCA to get the major and minor axis for the ellipse

Comment: So you have D(x,y,z) as directional vector of major semiaxis?

Comment: Such a cone is convex. Draw a line from the vertex of the cone through the point in question and calculate it's intersection with the plane the base is in. Then check whether that intersection is in the ellipse. If not, the point is not in the cone. If yes, check whether the point lies on the same side of the plane just mentioned as the vertex of the cone and (if yes) calculate it's distance to the plane. If it's closer to the plane than the vertex it's in the cone. If you don't know how to do some of these tasks consider asking at math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

Take the line that goes through V and P, find the intersection point of this line with the plane of the cone base. Test if this intersection point is within the base ellipse.

edit: I've just expanded the comments - what Thomas said.