# JAVA Checking if a 3D object is within another 3D object/Bounds

Tags: java, object, 3d, physics, contains

I am working on a project on particle simulation and, in order to simulate a correct physical behavior, I need to make my objects collide and bounce off. The thing is that I also need to check whether or not a particle is within the central object (a cone). 
 I know that in the Sphere class , as well as in other primitives from vecmath, there is a function .intersect(), which is perfect for collisions. However, I do not find a function .contains() to check whether one object is within another (like in the 2D library). 
Any of you got any suggestions and/or other libraries to implement that?
 Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify if point is inside a cone in 3D space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768142/verify-if-point-is-inside-a-cone-in-3d-space)

Comment: thx a lot. i guess this is a mathematical approach, I thought more of some API/classes that allow to check this for any object

Comment: I'm sure it exists, but it is usually not encouraged to ask for suggestions of libraries / APIs. See [this help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), item 5.