# How to detect if a point is inside a 3d cone

Tags: 3d, collision

I want to write a simple program that constructs a 3d cone (does not need to render) and takes a point and tells if that point is inside a cone (single cone) in c++.

as we do in the circle with center at h,k and point in x,y as `(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 - r^2 = 0` if answer is equal to zero the point lies on the boundary, if less than zero it will be inside the circle and if greater than zero it will be outside the circle so i want this type of simple equation that i can write into a function and return if the point is inside the cone or outside the cone

that pseudo code shall look like 
the pseudo code for circle:

```
bool isInsideCircle(Circle circle, Point point)  // circle (radius, center(x,y)), point (x,y)
{

   if ( square(point.x - circle.center.x) + square(point.y - circle.center.y) - square(r) < 0)
      return true
   else 
      return false
}
```

the pseudo code for cone

```
bool isInsideCone(Cone cone, Point point) // Point (x,y,z)
{
   if (here i want this equation which tests that if a point is inside the cone)
      return true
   else
      return false
}
```

as i know about a cone that it has (height radius and angle theata) in 3d
now i am not sure how to do this as i am week in mathematics too, 
this was my first question so now i hope it will be a little bit better for every one to understand

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very vague. in fact I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. What have you tried? do you have some code that you've tried? even if it isn't working? if so - you must show it to us (don't paste it in the comments, edit your question and add it there). Do you have some pseudo-code for how you'd like it to work? did you get an error message? add these to your question too (again: NOT in the comments, edit your question and add it).

Comment: what i want to do is write a function that takes a cone object and a point and tells whether that point lies inside of that cone or not.  
as we do in the circle with center at h,k and point in x,y as 
(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 - r^2 = 0
if answer is equal to zero the point lies on the boundary, if less than zero it will be inside the circle and if greater than zero it will be outside the circle
so i want this type of simple equation that i can write into a function and return if the point is inside the cone or outside the cone ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify if point is inside a cone in 3D space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768142/verify-if-point-is-inside-a-cone-in-3d-space)